# How to copy MS Word Table with Images to MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a Word document that has tables, contain images. When I copy the table and paste in Excel, it losses the applied formats,once Row from Word table is copying in multiple Rows in Excel.

Is there any way I can copy the table with images from MS Word to MS Excel without changing the formatting?

Comment: The problem is probably having line breaks in the cells, not the pictures. Try to replace all paragraph breaks (`^p`) to manual line breaks (`^l`) before copying to Excel.

Comment: Based on my tests, If the table is with images and multi-line text (with line breaks) in  cells. When I copy it and paste in Excel, the merged rows will appear. In addition, the images aren't inserted in the original cells. The images are floating above the table.